# SwiftUI, How to set Text width correctly?

Tags: text, swiftui, width

I have a very simple `ContentView`, The `Text`'s width set to `68`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .frame(width: 68)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

But in **Debug View Hierarchy** I can see the `Text`'s width is not 68 at all, instead, the wrapper width of the `Text`is 68. Did I miss something?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text` isn't greedy by default and won't take all the space it's got available to it unless it's needed. Due to the extra width not being needed, it won't use it.

The width of the `VStack` is `68` as it's sized based on the size of it's child views, in this case it's only child view is explicitly saying it's width is `68`, so the width of the `VSTack` will be `68` and since the `Text` isn't greedy in this case, it'll only take up the horizontal space that it needs. This leads to the width of the `Text` being less than the width of the `VSTack`.

If you don't explicitly set the width of the `Text` you will see that the width of the `VStack` will match the width of the view it contains.

Answer (score 1):

The frame is 68 wide but the Text inside it doesn't need that much so there is a gap. View modifiers usually wrap what's inside in an outer view, e.g.

`myView.frame()` is essentially doing:

```
FrameView {
    myView
}
```

If you want bigger text you could increase the font size ;-)